# Open local file for direct editing and save from local server

Tags: java, javascript, python, .net

I have some file links in my web page in my local server.
I want when the users click on that link the file will be open then user will modify the file content and save the file(the modified content will be saved to the original file).

As "file" protocol is not supported I have used applet(self signed)  for that  using code

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(filePath));
```

But now every time the browser showing a warning.

Is the any other solution as there are more than 40 users it is not possible to do some manual hack and the file type may varies.

I have tried a

```
Window registry hack
```

But it is showing a dialog to associate the file type to a program.

OS: Windows
Browser: IE/FireFox/Chrome
File: any type of file

If it is possible by installing a exe/plugin ?

I need one time setup only.

Comment: Buy a proper certificate from a trusted certificate authority.

Comment: Will that will not through warning message in the new JRE update 51 ?

Answer (score 0):

using normal Http what you need to do is a GET -> Local Modidy -> POST

Rather than this try something like webDav

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV

and for Java

http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jackrabbit-webdav-library.html